# How to call a class constructor in one of its methods?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a class that I want to construct from a user provided file contents.

When I create a FileReader object and add an onload function to it, I cannot call a class fields nor methods with `this` keyword.

So I have this class and function:

```js
class Dictionary {
    constructor(words) {
        ...
        this.words = words;     
        ...   
    }
 ...
}

function createDictionaryFromFile(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
        dictionary = new Dictionary(reader.result);
    }     
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

but I don't want to have dictionary object creating function outside of class (I want to hide createDictionaryFromFile function, preferably in Dictionary class)

How to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just a other example:

```js
class Dictionary {
  constructor(words) {
    this.words = words
  }
  
  static fromBlobLike(file) {
    return file.text().then(t => new Dictionary(t))
  }
}

Dictionary.fromBlobLike( new File(['abc'], 'hello.txt') ).then(console.log)
Dictionary.fromBlobLike( new Blob(['def']) ).then(console.log)
Dictionary.fromBlobLike( new Response(['ghi']) ).then(console.log)
```

---

But I do not think the Dictionary class should be responsible for reading files.
If you look at it from a [onion architecture](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/understanding-onion-architecture.html) perspective then the core components should only handle logics and then the 2nd layer is os/web/node/deno/react-native responsibility to read/write and making networks calls

Comment: I previously considered whether this should be another class, but not thinking much I decided to try to pack this function into the Dictionary. Thanks for the commend about onion architecture, I didn't know about it

Answer (score 1):

In more recent dialects of JS, you can make the function a *static method* of the class. That would look like this:

```js
class Dictionary {
    constructor(words) {
        ...
        this.words = words;     
        ...   
    }

    static createFromFile(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function() {
            dictionary = new Dictionary(reader.result);
        }     
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
    ...
}
```

You would then call it as `Dictionary.createFromFile(...)`. Note that you aren't actually returning the dictionary from this function. To do so, you'll need an asynchronous approach like a promise or callback.